# PFUbiquity error when using Core Data and iCloud

Tags: core-data, ios8, icloud

I am using iCloud to sync my Core Data store. This works fine. I just noticed that when I launch the app I get the following error message. Is this normal? Is there something I can do to prevent it?

Thanks

```
2014-12-06 10:06:37.337 -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](808): CoreData: Ubiquity:  nobody~sim352B6DF3-0975-5C4B-B561-086A3032D6EA:ContentKeyName
Using local storage: 1
2014-12-06 10:06:37.382 __60-[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant canReadFromUbiquityRootLocation:]_block_invoke682(1476): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Attempting to download Peers hit a serious error for peers to download Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (BRCloudDocsErrorDomain error 5 - No document at URL)" UserInfo=0x7ff77ac9b110 {NSDescription=No document at URL, NSFilePath=/Users/dev/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0AC7A779-9C6C-4A6C-91C5-D1973CE278D9/data/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~app~container/Data/.DS_Store, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff77ac990d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"} with userInfo {
    NSDescription = "No document at URL";
    NSFilePath = "/Users/dev/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0AC7A779-9C6C-4A6C-91C5-D1973CE278D9/data/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~app~container/Data/.DS_Store";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\" UserInfo=0x7ff77ac9bee0 {NSDescription=No such file or directory}";
}
2014-12-06 10:06:37.409 -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](808): CoreData: Ubiquity:  nobody~sim352B6DF3-0975-5C4B-B561-086A3032D6EA:ContentKeyName
Using local storage: 0
```

Comment: It sounds like it's saying that it can't find your document. Does your document actually seem to be missing?

Comment: not that I am aware of - it loads the data. But why does it even need the .DS_Store?

Comment: i am trying to use icloud with core data as well. it seems to work fine for me too but i get the same error message. the documentation doesn't mention anything about this error. not sure what to do.

note, the app aborts on the device but works fine on the simulator!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm not sure if it's an error or a notification. I'm getting the storage code specified in Apple's documentation as I run through their programming guide. but when I get to `willChange` my app crashes.

Comment: Nope - still happens every now and then...

Comment: I'm getting this same error. My app, which uses Core Data/iCloud is not consistently syncing for me or my users.

Comment: I'm getting the same error and the sync does not work correctly. Does anyone has a solution? I just made a work around in that I rebuilt the store from the iCloud store - but this is not really a solution.

Comment: I have the same problem. Please someone post the solution for this.

Answer (score -2):

Based on my testing, here's what I believe is the problem.

When your local Core Data resources sync with iCloud, any rows deleted on another device are deleted.  More rows can be deleted through the de-dupe process.

In memory you may be holding ManagedObjects which represent deleted rows directly, or may be related to those rows.

So, when you access the properties of those rows, the fault process expects to find Core Data rows, but it doesn't.  The inconsistency causes the error.

My solution:  Refresh all ManagedObject subclassed objects whenever you receive a NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification or NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification

This worked for me.  Hopefully, someone else can profit from this too.